# Homepage Slow to Load

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, html

When I go to the homepage of my website after clearing my cache and history, it oftentimes takes up to 10 s to load, but it is sporadic. Sometimes it loads quickly; other times it does not. Because we are new, this is obviously a huge barrier to customer acquisition.

The website is being hosted via AWS on an EC2 instance, and the homepage is static (i.e. no data being served from a DB). Additionally, our time to first byte is very quick -- 0.3 s -- and the load time (according to pingdom.com) is between 0.9 and 4 s.

How can I better troubleshoot the underlying problem? Is there something blatantly wrong with my HTML or CSS? I have not been able to figure this out.

Website: www.gather.kitchen

Addison

Comment: Your page took a little less than a second to load for me. Maybe its your network? Regardless, you can host your static homepage on S3 and utilize Cloudfront distribution for faster responses.

Comment: What web server are you running, apache, nginx, other? What EC2 instance size are you using? What is your server's CPU and RAM usage? How many connections per second is your server having to handle? I just tried to load your site and it took over 20 seconds to get any response, so obviously something is going on. If you aren't overloaded with traffic then perhaps your web server is misconfigured. Placing a CDN such as CloudFront or CloudFlare in front of your site would definitely help.

Comment: I'm running an Apache server on a t2.micro instance. CPU usage is around 0.5% and memory usage on the actual Ubuntu Linux machine is 27%. Our website is not popular yet, so we're serving fewer than 1 connection per second.

Comment: I appreciate your help -- sounds like I need to serve our static content through S3 or CloudFront.

Comment: S3 alone will not be fast. Switching from EC2 to S3 will however remove any CPU limitations you may be running into. Regardless of using EC2 or S3 you need to use a CDN like CloudFront or CloudFlare in order to speed up delivery of your website. I personally like CloudFlare much better than CloudFront in almost every scenario. Plus it's cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

I am not having any trouble loading your website, see the picture for my loading times. Maybe it is your internet connection that causes the slow loading times?

It is a good idea anyway to improve your websites loading time, Google will rank you higher this way and your customers might like it too ;) You can achieve this by making the following modifications to your website

1. Minify your CSS (http://cssminifier.com), PHP and Javascript.
2. Compress your images with the .htaccess file (google .htaccess compress images).
3. Never ever use images that are too big, this causes the most problems with the loading time of websites as images use a lot of bandwidth.

[loading times website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljshP.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Do you mind telling me what region you're located in? East coast, west coast, midwest?

Comment: I am located in the Netherlands, in Europe. So i'd say I am the closes to the East coast.