# Configuring EC2 + CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

Does anyone have a good tutorial on configuring an EC2 instance with CloudFront? I cannot find a useful, actionable tutorial anywhere -- only configuring CloudFront with S3 -- and although I have all the components in place, CloudFront is not working for me. I have the following items:

- **EC2**: t2.micro instance running and hosting https://www.gather.kitchen
- **Load Balancer**: HTTP forwarding to HTTPS. 1 instance, but 0 of 1 instances in service
- **CloudFront**: Deployed and enabled with origin as Load Balancer DNA name; CNAMEs are www.gather.kitchen and gather.kitchen

The 1 instance that is erroring out says: *Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively*. I don't know if I am missing something or what. In general, my website is very slow to open during the first connect, which has been a huge barrier to customer acquisition, so I'm using CloudFront to speed up delivery.

See my post from yesterday, which inspired me to use CloudFront. [Homepage Slow to Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789931/homepage-slow-to-load/33790495?noredirect=1#comment55362475_33790495)

Comment: CloudFront isn't even in the equation right now, so you need to focus on what's going on with the ELB.  Also, your DNS is configured incorrectly, returning both a public and private IP address -- 2 `A` records.

Comment: Is it possible that the instance on my ELB is out of service because I'm returning 2 A records? And will it suffice to simply remove the private IP address from my DNS configuration? Maybe that explains why my site takes so long to connect.

Comment: Removing the private IP definitely needs to happen, and seems like it may be a major contributor to the slow load, but is not related to the failed health check.  That is an error in your ELB config, possibly in the health check setup itself.  Check the web server log, see if you see health checks coming in from the ELB.